# Should the "optimized out" value be a random or not?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

I want to check how optimization options of `gcc` to affect the program, and the code is like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        A() {
                a[0] = 10;
                a[1] = 20;
                empty;
        }
        int a[5];
        bool empty;
};

int main(void){
        A a;

        std::cout << a.empty << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Since `empty` member isn't assigned value in constructor, I expect it is a random value. Compile and run it:

```
# g++ -g test.cpp
# ./a.out
254
# ./a.out
254
# ./a.out
253
# ./a.out
253
```

The result is as my expected. Then I use `-O2` compile option:

```
# g++ -g -O2 test.cpp
# ./a.out
0
# ./a.out
0
# ./a.out
0
# ./a.out
0
```

It seems always `0`. I use `gdb` to debug the program:

```
14      int main(void){
(gdb) n
17                      std::cout << a.empty << std::endl;
(gdb) p a
$1 = {
  a = {[0] = 10, [1] = 20, [2] = <optimized out>, [3] = <optimized out>, [4] = <optimized out>},
  empty = <optimized out>
}
```

I just want to make sure since the `empty` is `optimized out`, its value should also be random, is it right?

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined.. So what ever happens here is totally not reproducable or in any kind representative... You just killed the legitimacy of your program, because the whole program is now undefined.

Comment: No, nobody promosed you that it will be random. Most of the time you are going to see a "previous" value left over in that storage location (memory or register) by previous user. It can be quite determininistic at least within a narrow time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninitialized values are just that: uninitalized. They have the value that is in that location in memory. It may be the same for multiple runs, or it may be "random". It depends on where in memory it is located, and what value resides in that memory and, quite plausibly, what other calls have been made prior to the call to the current function, and what data they operated on. In this case, your code is in `main`, so there is not much variation in the calls that go on before `main` (unless you change the system in general, swap compilers etc).

On some systems, for some data types, that could lead to a trap - either because uninitialized data has the wrong parity values, or because the value itself is invalid (e.g. trying to load a floating point number that has an invalid combination of bits, loading a "far" pointer on a protected mode x86-system when the segment part of the address is not a valid segment descriptor index, etc)

It is "non deterministic" more than "random" - there is no way to look at the code to figure out what the value should be. But thinking that it should be a good source of random numbers is incorrect. It's very often "guessable" based on what happened before - just that you have to know "how did we get here, and what happened on the way", rather than just reading the value in the source-code to determine what it's value is.

Answer (score 2):

I understand why you might think that it should be random, but what you're asking for is to have a garbage value with certain characteristics. In other words: You want undefined behavior to be defined. Sorry, but you can't ask for that! It's random when you average over all computers in the world. Not on your specific, small program on your tiny laptop. It's the same reason why [random errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) are not easily discovered on a single computer, because they're random over many uses over many computers.